# If the name of an idol is used as an exclamation by someone, is laughing forbidden?

Tags: halacha, chilul-kidush-hashem

The name of a certain idol is commonly used (in the United States at least) as an exclamation, typically displaying surprise/anger etc.

Suppose someone was describing their disdain over something in a humorous way and ended their statement with using the name of an idol as an exclamation.

Is it forbidden to laugh at the statement?

Comment: Aren't all idols a joke?

Answer (score 10):

You are allowed to do a lot more than laugh, I am afraid.  In a very unusual display of contempt, the Talmud says:

> Rabbi Nachman said: All foul language is forbidden except where directed at idolatry, in which case it is permitted… 
>   Rabbi Huna ben Manoah said in the name of Rabbi Aha the son of Rabbi Ika: A Jew is permitted to tell [an idolater], “Take your idol and stick it up your rear end.” [Megillah 25b]

Comment: Where are you getting your translation from? I've always understand 'Leitzanusa' as 'mockery', not 'foul language' (and FWIW, Sefaria translates it as mockery as well).

Comment: @Salmononius2 --  After "mockery" Sefaria adds, editorially, "and obscenity" -- just to make the point clear: https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.25b.17?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi don't be afraid

Comment: That's laughing at. I think the question was laughing with.